# How to check which part of page is an article?

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping

I would like to create a similar tool to Instapaper or Readability and I wonder what is the best way to find and get text from a web page. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Since you did not talk about technolgies or algorithms, the absolute best way is to open your web browser, open the desired web page, copy the relevant text and paste it to your database.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad to give a concrete answer to, but you can separate this question into three concerns:

1. A way to grab web resources. `libcurl` for example, or just about anything able to talk `HTTP`.
2. A `DOM` parser.  Python has `xml.dom.minidom`, for example.
3. An algorithm for traversing the `DOM` tree and extracting text.  Be it scanning for elements with `class=article`, or `<div>`s with more than 1024 characters etc., is entirely up to you.  You will need experimentation to get this right.

I suggest asking separate questions for each of these concerns.  After doing research on each, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea to get you started in Ruby. Just tested the code below and it is working fine for me. Have a look it might help you.

```
require 'open-uri'    
require 'cgi'    
require 'nokogiri'

$url='http://www.stackoverflow.com'

$txt_file = open($url)   

$raw_contents = $txt_file.read

$html = Nokogiri::HTML(CGI.unescapeHTML($raw_contents)).content
#strip the web page fetched out of all hmtl tags and encoded chars

$txt_file = File.new('c:\ruby193\bin\web-content\stack.txt', "w")
#stack.txt now contains a stripped, pure txt file which you can manipulate further

$txt_file.write($html)    
$txt_file.close

puts 'Here is the stripped text of your webpage\n'+$html
```